# vtk and three.js synchronization

Tags: web, three.js, vtk

I'm working on a web application that allows you to send from the server to the client a picture made ​​with VTK. But how do you know the speed of the Internet depends on the speed, well, the file system. And to speed up the work, I decided to add to the client webGL. And now the question arose in the data synchronization. In VTK rotates the camera around the object, after many attempts, I could not do on the client side, the camera works well (with the change of coordinates the camera), but was able to make correct the rotation of the object. In this some questions:
 1. is any ideas with camera?
 2. or it will be easy to change rotation in vtk?

### Update:

I make a camera and it's synchroniz with vtk, but know i have a problem with viewUp vector, on client after rising phi more than 90 it's became (0,-1,0) and when i make SetViewUp(0,-1,0) nothing changed

#### Javascript:

```
    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if ( paused ) {
                return;
            }

            if ( !moving ) {
                lastLeft = e.clientX;
                lastTop = e.clientY;
                moving = true;
            }

            // horizontal
            theta = - ( ( event.clientX - lastLeft ) * 360 /window.innerWidth ) + onMouseDownTheta;
            phi = ( ( event.clientY - lastTop ) * 360 /window.innerHeight ) + onMouseDownPhi;



            //phi = Math.min( 90, Math.max( -90, phi ) );
            var cosPhi = Math.cos( phi * Math.PI / 180 );
            var sinPhi = Math.sin( phi * Math.PI / 180 );
            var sinTheta = Math.sin( theta * Math.PI / 180 );
            var cosTheta = Math.cos( theta * Math.PI / 180 );


            //trace('data_move');trace(radious);trace(theta);trace(phi);trace(camera.up);   

            camera.position.x = radious * cosTheta * cosPhi;
            camera.position.y = radious * sinPhi;
            camera.position.z = radious * sinTheta * cosPhi;

            var u;
            if (phi<0)  phi=2*180+phi;
            if (phi>2*180)  phi=phi-2*180;

            if ((phi>180/2)&&(phi<3*180/2))
                u=-1;
            else
                u=1;

            camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, u, 0);
            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(FocalPoint[0],FocalPoint[1],FocalPoint[2]))
            trace('data_move');trace(FocalPoint);trace(camera.up);  

            camera.updateMatrix();

        });
        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
            paused = false;
            lastLeft = e.clientX;
            lastTop = e.clientY;
            onMouseDownTheta = theta;
            onMouseDownPhi = phi;

        });
        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
            moving = paused = true;
            counter = 0
            trace('data_move');trace(camera.position);trace(camera.up); 
            comm.makeRequest("vtk", {
                mode: curVtkConf.mode,
                command: "set_camera",
                up: {'x': camera.up.x,'y': camera.up.y,'z': camera.up.z},
                position: {'x': camera.position.x,'y': camera.position.y,'z': camera.position.z},
            });
        });
```

#### Phyton:

```
 def set_camera(self, position, up):
    '''
    Поворот в жестко заданную позицию.
    '''
    self.move_to_origin()
    bounds = self.src_actor.GetBounds()
    camera = self.renderer.GetActiveCamera()
    x, y, z = camera.GetPosition()
    edge = None
    camera.SetPosition(position['x'], position['y'], position['z'])
    camera.SetViewUp(up['x'], up['y'], up['z'])
    self.world_coords_to_pixel_ratio = self._get_world_coords_to_pixel_ratio()
    camera.OrthogonalizeViewUp()
    camera.SetRoll(0)
    self.renderer.ResetCameraClippingRange()
    self.renderer.ResetCamera()
```

### Update2:

Now also i have some problems with rotation. The model just changed it size while rotating

#### Solved: by moving model to the center

## Solved at all))

Comment: What's VTK for you? For me is a file format.

Comment: @mrdoob If you hover mouse over the tag it gives you a short cummary

Comment: The question is little unclear. Could you please add more structure to your question and maybe images.

Comment: The main question is how to synchronize the process of rotating on the client and server. In its current form, we catches the mouse movement on the client send the request to the server that contains the dx and dy, and get back to the rendered image.Since I was not originally involved in this project I'm not really familiar with VTK. But the at least I realized that rotation in the VTK Object Implemented by rotating the camera in spherical coordinates.

Comment: So I ask, how can I synchronize the rotation, because I could not write the same camera as in VTK